# Prove that there is a least upper bound in the set E

Tags: maxima-minima, upper-lower-bounds

$$E = \{x \in Q \mid x^2 < 2\}$$

This was a homework problem where I had to prove that there is a $LUB$ in E. I answered that there is not because $\sqrt2$ is not in the set of rational numbers. The professor marked it wrong without explanation so I would really appreciate it if someone shed some light on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the question **exactly** right?  If it was "prove that $E$ has a lub in $\Bbb R$" that would be completely different.

Comment: Exactly, that does make sense. However, that was not the question. Word by word, the questions states: for each set that is bounded above, determine its least upper bound. There are other sets, not related to the problem.

Comment: The least upper bounded of $E$ is $\sqrt{2} \notin E$.  That's the whole subject of a first course in real analysis.

Comment: So you can answer with $\sqrt2 \notin E$?

Comment: "For each set that is bounded above, determine its least upper bound" - probably "least upper bound in $\Bbb R$" is assumed, though it would have been better if the question had stated this clearly.  In any case it certainly doesn't appear to ask for a lub **in the set $E$ itself**, as you have in the second line of your post.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I thought it was assumed in E, but it seems that is not the case. I appreciate both help.